# Bash script keep execute the background script

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a bash script that execute another script for NIPT analysis, and this script I want to worked independently. However, when running it constantly keep execute the script `run.sh` with the first fastq file in the folder. I don't know what's wrong with my script

```
#!/bin/bash
signalfile="signal/signal"
loopfile="signal/loop"
inputdir="/home/ubuntu/Documents/test/8/raw"
wk_p_file="signal/working_processors"
r=`cat $loopfile`

#echo $signalfile
#echo $loopfile
#echo $r
checkloop(){
while [ "$r" == "1" ]
    do 
        loop=`cat $signalfile`
        #echo $loop
        if [[ "$loop" == "0" ]]
        then
#           echo "no signal found"
            sleep 10s
        elif [[ "$loop" == "1" ]]
        then
            num_count=$(ls $inputdir | grep -c "\.fq.gz$")
            echo $num_count
            if [[ "$num_count" == "0" ]]
            then
#               echo "No files found"
                sleep 10s
            else
                for file in $inputdir"/*" 
                do  
                    tgchay="$( date +"%d%m%y-%T" )"
                    echo "Begin processing with $( basename $file )"
                    nohup ./run.sh $file > "run-$tgchay" &
                done
            fi
        fi
        r=`cat $loopfile`
    done
if [ "$r" == "0" ]
then
    echo "Loop terminated by emergency switch!"
fi
}

checkloop
```

Comment: Can you make a zip file with all those files so I can test on my server? I don't know what's the content for the signal file and the loop file

Comment: As the bash tag you used instructs: "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.". Once you've fixed the issues that tool tells you about then let us know if you still have a question and [edit] your question to replace your current script with the fixed one.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
for file in $inputdir"/*"
```

executes the loop exactly once, with `file` set to the string `/home/ubuntu/Documents/test/8/raw/*`. Therefore, you don't need a loop, but could simply write

```
file=$inputdir"/*"
```

instead. In

```
nohup ./run.sh $file
```

the asterisk in this string will then be expanded, and `run.sh` gets as parameters all the files in the `raw` directory. This happens for every time the outside `while` loop is executed. Unles the content of the directory `raw` changes during these executions, `run.sh` will always see the same files.

For further debugging, I suggest that you turn on `set -x` in your `checkloop` function and analyze the output on stderr.